# Check the length and add corresponding column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with two columns. Depending on the length of the data in one column, I need to join the next column. How can i proceed with this. I have the base SQL up but i cant join the columns together and display both data into one table.

The current table is like this :

```
     ID        Code
 ----------   ----------
    ST01         00
    ST0105       05
    ET2256       56
```

After a SELECT QUERY, I would like to have

```
      ID        
 ----------   
    ST0100      
    ST0105      
    ET2256
```

As you can see when **ST01** is lesser than 5 characters i will need to add the Code column to it. When the length of the ID is more i do not need to add. How can i achieve. The DB is in production am I am unable to edit, cause all the old applications are configured and running. But the application which I am building uses the 7 character format. So I cant edit the table. I will need to do a select statement only.

```
SELECT 
CASE ID
WHEN ((LEN(ID))<>5) THEN ID=(RTRIM(ID)+LTRIM(Code))
FROM tblID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: You say less than 5 characters but you're comparing to `unequal 5`, 6 will match as well. Also, don't use an `=` in a case: `CASE WHEN a=b THEN a ELSE c END AS ID`

Comment: What is the maximum possible length for ID? Always 6 letters?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Max is 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation I'm guessing:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN ((LEN(ID))<5) THEN (RTRIM(ID)+LTRIM(Code)) ELSE ID END AS ID
FROM tblID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The syntax of your `CASE` was a bit off, as well as the comparison on length (`<>5` vs `<5`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
          CASE 
             WHEN LEN(ID) < 6 THEN LEFT(ID + Code),6)
             ELSE ID
          END AS Code
FROM      tblID
ORDER BY  ID DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(ID) <> 6 THEN SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 6-LEN(Code)) + Code
        ELSE ID
    END as Code
FROM tblID
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING()` is missing an argument. Also, `CONCAT()` is a 2012 function and it does not seem as if the OP has made clear which version is in use

Comment: @MarkD Using 2005 MSSQL

Comment: Please see revised query, which is compatible with MSSQL 2005, above.